# Chrome Extension Host Registration not working in windows

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I want to run console app by clicking button on webpage
Console app will get Information and put in clipboard, and then I will get that information on webpage.
I am following [this blog](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1265249/Read-Emirates-ID-in-a-Web-Application)
I did this 3-4 times, all other things looks fine, but console app is not being called/executed.

I am getting these errors.
on webpage console
`Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.`
on background file
`Unchecked runtime.lastError: Specified native messaging host not found.`
`Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.`

my codes are

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "EID Reader",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Read Emirates ID",

"permissions": [ "contextMenus", "activeTab", "clipboardRead", "nativeMessaging" ],
"icons": {
  "16": "eid16.png",
  "48": "eid48.png",
  "128": "eid128.png"
},
"background": {
  "scripts": [ "eid.js" ]
},
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file://*/*"],
    "js": [ "content_script.js", "jquery-3.3.1.js" ],
    "all_frames": true,
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }
]
}
```

content_script.js

```
    // Listener to catch the event raised by the webpage button
       document.addEventListener("EID_EVENT", function (data) {
       // send message to background process to read emirates ID and send back the data
       chrome.runtime.sendMessage("ifligfijbkpijeafdfbpljjibfbppmeb", function (response) {
       });
    });

// Listener to catch the data coming from the background process
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.action == 'EID_DATA') {
        //Parse the data and fill the form accordingly
        try {
            var json = $.parseJSON(msg.response);
            $(json).each(function (i, val) {
                $.each(val, function (key, value) {
                    if (key == 'EIDNumber')
                        $("#txtNumber").val(value);
                    if (key == 'Name')
                        $("#txtName").val(value);
                    if (key == 'Email')
                        $("#txtEmail").val(value);
                    if (key == 'PassportNumber')
                        $("#txtPassport").val(value);
                });
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            var error = "error" + e;
        }
    }
});
```

eid.js (background)

```
var port = null;
var tabId = null;
/* listener for messages coming from the content_scrip */
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    tabId=sender.tab.id;
    var hostName = "ae.eid.chrome";
    port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);     
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected); 
});


/* THIS WILL BE CALLED ONCE EXE FINISH */
function onDisconnected() {

    port = null;
    SendResponse();
}

function SendResponse() {
    //create a textarea, focus on it, and make a "paste" command to get the clipboard, then send the pasted value back to the content_script
    bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    bg.document.body.innerHTML = ""; // clear the background page
    var helper = null;
    if (helper == null) {
        helper = bg.document.createElement("textarea");
        helper.style.position = "absolute";
        helper.style.border = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(helper);
    }

    //Focus the textarea
    helper.select();

    // perform a Paste in the selected control, here the textarea
    bg.document.execCommand("Paste"); 

    // Send data back to content_script
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { action: "EID_DATA", response: helper.value }, function (response) { });
}
```

ae.eid.chrome.json

```
{
"name": "ae.eid.chrome",
"description": "chrome extension to read EID",
"path": "EIDSampleConsole.exe",
"type": "stdio",
"allowed_origins": [
  "chrome-extension://ifligfijbkpijeafdfbpljjibfbppmeb/"
]
}
```

install_host.bat

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\ae.eid.chrome" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%~dp0ae.eid.chrome.json" /f
```

I spent 2 days didnot get anything helpful.
Am I doing some error or Google Chrome prevented or changed the way to register host.

Comment: Things to try, shouldn't take more than a few minutes: 0) Make sure the official [example app+host](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#examples) runs on your computer. 1) Enable [chrome logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) and check the log file for errors, 2) Use [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and check how Chrome locates/run the host file. 3) To hide the "message port closed" errors simply remove callback from both sendMessage calls, you're not using it anyway.

Comment: I'd say the only obviously suspicious thing is the lack of full path in `"path": "EIDSampleConsole.exe"`.

Comment: after writing this question and inplementing `example app host` I am new in extension development for example app host i do not see any icon in chrome but I have created registery key. now my application if throwing different error i.e `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Native host has exited.` on background file console. and also light blinks in the card reader.

Comment: This new info doesn't help identify the problem. Try the other things I suggested.

Comment: It is working with a bug, Webpage is calling exe but do not wait for response and right away throwing `Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.` while background console waits for result and on completion shows `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Native host has exited.` and `Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.` while textboxes are also filed with data from card.

Comment: 1) The host exe must be incorrectly processing the stdio protocol. 2) To hide the "message port closed" errors see my first comment.

Comment: you are great @wOxxOm, A quick question. It normally takes 3-6 seconds to read card data. what if I want to abort it in middle.

Comment: I can create a vairable aborted=false and make it true on btnAbort.click and then do not render data of page, but is there some standard method to stop the process.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved all the issues and posted all the steps at

http://www.codingsips.com/emirates-id-reader-and-google-chrome-via-extension-and-console-app/

Also I have published chrome extension, it you follow above steps the same extension will also work for you

chrome extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adcs-eid-reader/ipcncgpbppgjclagpdlodiiapmggolkf